# What is faster the main network or Ropsten?

Tags: ropsten, network

Ropsten sometimes works VERY slowly.

What's about the main network? What is usually faster the main network or Ropsten?

I do not yet have Ether to try to deploy something on main network and I want to ask in advance.

I want to deploy a testing contract and make sure my web3.js code works with my contract in a right way.

---

Right now my Ethereum Wallet is stuck "Looking for peers..." (in Ropsten) and so far found zero peers. It is stalled on this stage about 40 minutes or so.

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean by "slow"? What are your expectations with regards to what you're doing? _What_ exactly are you trying to do that you think is taking too much time? (Deploying a contract?)

Comment: How fast transaction are confirmed depends on your gas price. For testing I'd use ganache, it mines blocks instantly. Sometimes Ropsten is attacked with spam transactions so you have to use higher fees. You can use alternative test networks Rinkeby or Kovan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather prefer Metamask extension for testing smart contract.
It gives an option for deploying smart contract on Ropsten and Testnet network without actually syncing whole chain.
Also you can get free Ether using Ropsten faucet for testing and deploying your contract.

Comment: You can also get ether on Rinkeby. And Ropsten IS a testnet.

Comment: Rinkeby requires that you have a Twitter or Facebook account. Not everybody is inclined to open one of those to use their testnet.